# How to hide NaN values in a pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a data set, which contains in one column some `NaN` values, where I do not have data for. The `pgfplotstable1` command displays them literally as `NaN`. How can I hide them, either by displaying them as `-` or completely hiding them?

Comment: You should provide the community with some data and code to play with. It'll help get answers your way faster. Help us help you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`clear infinite` does exactly that, it removes nan and inf entries in a table.

[image: table output]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
1 2
3 nan
5 6
7 nan
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[clear infinite]\datatable
\end{document}
```

Comment: To my future self: `empty cells with={\ensuremath{-}}`  replaces NaNs.